# Reducing the size of image

Tags: qt

I'm trying to insert an image into my project. I wrote the following code:

```
void MainWindow::on_Layer_Updated(int arg1)
{
    if(ui->scrnCheck1->checkState() == Qt::Checked && ui->insCheck1->checkState() == Qt::Checked && ui->scrnCheck2->checkState() == Qt::Checked && ui->sheathCheck1->checkState() == Qt::Checked
            && ui->insCheck3->checkState() == Qt::Checked && ui->concentricCheck2->checkState() == Qt::Checked && ui->insCheck2->checkState() == Qt::Checked && ui->armorCheck->checkState() == Qt::Checked
            && ui->jacketCheck->checkState() == Qt::Checked)
    {
        QImage image;

        image.load(":/CondScrnInsScrnSheathInsCentricInsWiresArmJacket.png");
        ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
        ui->frame_10->setMinimumHeight(image.size().height() + 20);
        ui->groupBox_3->setMinimumHeight(ui->frame_10->size().height() + 20);
    }
```

When I'm running the program the image is getting popped up but the size of the image is large that it is overlapping with another grid. So I reduced the image view->height size in mainwindow.ui. Then only half of the image is displayed. How can I adjust the image so that it will not overlap with the other grid?

Comment: You can just create a QPixmap directly with `QPixmap(":image")`, instead of a QImage and converting it. And also have you tried setting the `QLabel->setScaledContents(true)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you end up with overlapping widgets, it means you didn't set up a layout for your main widget, or for any container widget inside it. Layouts prevent widgets from overlapping.

To reduce the size of the image, use QImage::scaled() or QPixmap::scaled().